# How to declare a type that works with a generic type T and an array of that generic type T

Tags: typescript

I am trying this in TypeScript

```
type ArrayOrSingle<T> = T | T[];

interface Test<T> {
    a: ArrayOrSingle<T>;
    b: (v: ArrayOrSingle<T>) => void;
}


const t: Test<number> = {
    a: 4,
    b: (v) => console.log(v)
}

t.b([2]);
```

Now I want to ensure consistency so that `t.b([2])` would raise an error because `a` is a `number` (and not `number[]`)

ChatGPT gave me a solution:

```
type ArrayOrSingle<T> = T extends any[] ? T[] : T;

interface Test<T, U extends ArrayOrSingle<T>> {
    a: U;
    b: (v: U) => void;
}

// This should give an error
const t1: Test<number, number> = {
    a: 4,
    b: (v: number[]) => console.log(v) // Error: 'v' should be a number, not number[]
}

// This should be okay
const t2: Test<number, number[]> = {
    a: [4],
    b: (v: number[]) => console.log(v) // 'v' should be a number array
}
```

But I would like a solution where I don't need to specify the type twice (e.g. `const t2: Test<number, number[]> = {`  I should be able to declare `const t2: Test<number> = {`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiA8nAygSwHYHMA2EAPACoB8UAvFCVAD40DaAugNwBQ7okNEAzsFIAaKAFUqsBMjRY8hUmQrVxEAB7AI2ACZ8x7KFAD8UAN76DFxAC4xHCxYBGNgBQA3G6ICUVCq4D2mFp2FgC+5jbYEK4QcBzsAPTxNAAWmLp8yX4ArvhaULiY0VCI2FAxcH5w7ADGftgCUMAAjDYk-ILYWQC2DjFKpubWUAAsQuZOUG4R3b1wLN6UFLX1foQAdPh+uG6eIuwhcYkpaVAZ2blQvVB+ANbINXUNwABMre1EnT19EmYGQ4zDZhjAwTKZQT6zeY+KDLPirCAbLY7MYHdhAA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Okay, will write soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is very similar to GPT's solution.

```
type ArrayOrSingle<T> = T extends any[] ? T[] : T;

interface Test<T extends ArrayOrSingle<unknown>> {
    a: T;
    b: (v: T) => void;
}

// This should give an error
const t1: Test<number> = {
    a: 4,
    b: (v: number[]) => console.log(v) // Error: 'v' should be a number, not number[]
}

// This should be okay
const t2: Test<number[]> = {
    a: [4],
    b: (v: number[]) => console.log(v) // 'v' should be a number array
}
```

Live Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiA8nAygSwHYHMA2EAPACoB8UAvFCVBAB7ATYAmAzlItiANoC6UAPw1+UAFw0A3AChpOJnABmiAMbQSENsFJ1GzdrATI0WPISIBXbAGtsAewDu2MhQDe0qJ84SSMr1AAjCQAKADcfAEoqClC7TBYZAF9ZAHoUmgALTA42DLsLfBYoXExQ6C46BDs4aRU7bC0oYABGH01tbAsAWwCIOApqd39ECQAWABoPLyCoMIlOnr7+KMoKOoa7QgA6fDtcMKi0qABRKrgJAHJQi6hc-MLA8qgF3rhx57tgZ+7X-mlk6RHEhZHJ5ApFXpQOzWZC1eqNYAAJjaWiILyWfAGUCGXhGUB4oz4k38Mzm30WcGW0Sg6zYmwgOz2BygRyuNzu4MenHJr04RhA-1S6WB2SgDmq1g4wDsdjhDS+wAAzCiOj8+licZ48RMpp5SaEVmt4fTGfsDYLpEqtgFgojDulobCrTaeIi+BFJCz0n04NUgA)

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. But I don't understand the use of 'unknown'. My understanding is that 'unkown' will always be the same type as 'T' .